# Have a Linux shell script stuff a string into a Windows user's copy/paste buffer

Tags: windows, linux, putty, paste

We have a script right now which our Windows users run on a Linux host by way of putty.  From time to time the script produces a string that the user must copy and paste into a Windows application.

Without running a full-blown X display server on the Windows box, I'd like to modify the script so that the string is populated in the Windows user's copy/paste buffer automatically so that it's more convenient for the user and so that we reduce the error rate (the workflow is clumsy enough, we'd like to make it a little less so).

Here's what I **don't** consider solutions:

1. Running a full blown X display manager on the Windows side just for this (if there exists a nearly invisible utility that enables *just this one feature* that's a different story)
2. Make the user stop running Windows
3. Rewrite any other applications

I have full control over the Windows user's environment (can set up whatever putty settings I need to) as well as the Linux host and every node in the network between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to do this I'd probably grab the sources to putty and modify it to suit.

Failing that I don't think you'll be able to easily do this; except by writing a small script on the Linux box that will open a socket to the a small windows deamon and send the text across to be put into the Windows clipboard.

Comment: The most elegant way to implement as a PuTTY enhancement would probably be to add a "ANSI Printer output goes to Clipboard" option.  The Linux scripts would then just use VT102 printer escapes to delimit the text that it wants to go to clipboard.

Comment: @caf: I like that idea - it's simple neat and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote script doesn't need full terminal support but only does simple `stdin`/`stdout` operation, then you might be able to use [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) to provide a simple text-only interface which can probably be scripted more easily than a full PuTTY window.

Comment: If using plink you may be able to put the output into the paste buffer with clip.exe (you may have to download and install it).
`plink login.example.com -l fred echo hello, world | clip`

Answer (score 0):

http://ericmason.net/2010/04/putty-ssh-windows-clipboard-integration/

This guy's script patches putty to just what was suggested above.  I think it would be more elegant to have just a printer driver you can install in windows to get text to the clipboard, rather than patching putty, but this works!